# Import a module in Python only if it doesn't already exist

Tags: python, module

I want to use a module, e.g. BeautifulSoup, in my Python code, so I usually add this to the top of the file:

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
```

However, when I distribute the module I'm writing, others may not have BeautifulSoup, so I'll just include it in my directory structure like so:

```
Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name
----                -------------     ------ ----
d----         9/19/2011   5:45 PM            BeautifulSoup
-a---         9/17/2011   8:06 PM       4212 myscript.py
```

Now, my modified myscript.py file will look like this at the top to reference the local copy of BeautifulSoup:

```
from BeautifulSoup.BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup, CData
```

But what if the developer who uses my library already has BeautifulSoup installed on their machine? I want to modify myscript.py so that it checks to see if BeautifulSoup is already installed, and if so, use the standard module. Otherwise, use the included one.

Using Pseudo-python:

```
if fBeautifulSoupIsInstalled:
    from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup, CData
else:
    from BeautifulSoup.BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup, CData
```

Is this possible? If so, how?

Comment: Taken from http://effbot.org/zone/import-confusion.htm : `When Python imports a module, it first checks the module registry (sys.modules) to see if the module is already imported. If that’s the case, Python uses the existing module object as is.`

Comment: Try to import it.  If it doesn't work, catch the ImportError and import from your local copy.  Name your local copy something else (myBeautifulSoup) so it doesn't hide the user installed module.

Comment: @mwan: Ben doesn't need to know if it's already *imported*, he needs to know if it's *already on the system*.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Usually the following pattern is used to handle this situation in Python.

First rename your BeautifulSoup module something else, e.g. MyBeautifulSoup

Then:

```
try:
    import BeautifulSoup # Standard
except ImportError:
    import MyBeautifulSoup as BeautifulSoup # internal distribution
```